# How to redirect the result of instanced rendering to different areas of the target texture?

Tags: opengl, rendering

I'm trying to create a series of depth maps (about 300 or more) with instanced rendering in opengl.

I have learned that vertices and data will be operated multiple passes in each instanced draw call, and the result of frame shader will accumulate in the attached frame buffer.

For the convenience of subsequent use, my initial plan was trying to render several low resolution depth maps to a high resolution texture. Like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lDEg.png (no instanced rendering, just multiple draw calls).

My current result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8WU.png (instanced rendering, INSTANCE_COUNT = 2, the resolution of depth map is 1/4 of target texture's). The depth maps in two different source spaces overlap together. I can't control the output of frame shader to the area I want.

Multiviewport rendering may solve this problem, and I'm working on it. I don't know if calling `glViewportIndexedf()` 300 times per frame will significantly affect performance when rendering a complex model.

Is there any other better way to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `glViewportArrayv` to set all viewports in one call. But I would rather use texture arrays instead of an atlas, then you don't need to have multiple viewports.

Comment: @ybungalobill, thanks for the answer. I just find the `GL_MAX_VIEWPORTS` is 16. This means I can only create up to 16 viewports. While `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` is 2048. I will try to use texture arrays.